# meteor setInterval - updating a string each second

Tags: timer, push, meteor

I am trying to create a timer and I my javascript file is:

```
function timer(){
  var date = new Date();
  Template.pomodoro.timer = function() { return date};
  Template.pomodoro.message = function() { return "test message"};

} 


if (Meteor.isClient) {
      Meteor.setInterval( timer(), 1000 );
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup

  });
}
```

I want to push to all the browser the same timer (computed server side) in order to get them synchronized.

the template updates only the first time, why is it not updated each second?

Thanks
Francesco

Answer (score 4):

Here is what worked for me regarding client side. I found pushing server time to client was easisest to achieve by putting current time into collection and simple use that value on a client.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.pomodoro.timer= function () {
        return Session.get("dateval");
    };
    Template.pomodoro.message= function () {
        return "My Message";
    };

    Meteor.setInterval( function () {
        Session.set("dateval",Date());
        console.log(Session.get("dateval")); 
    }, 1000 );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try:**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
      Meteor.setInterval( function(){timer()}, 1000 );
}
```

**Or:**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
      Meteor.setInterval( timer, 1000 );
}
```

This is because first argument of setInterval must be function pointer, and you're using `()` that means that you're executing function instead of passing it.